# getting rid of redundant code between html pages

Tags: html, css, database, performance, redundancy

So I'm working on producing my own version of a web/db project my friend was given in school. This is my first project in either area and I'm still learning. Part of the project description mentions all of the pages the client wants. I'm solving this by making an unordered list of links to the different pages with appropriate labels. Complex, I know.

Then I realized that every page will have this. My question is this: is there a way to class certain portions of code in html, so I can just have a "navigation list" in each page, instead of the full code of the list and everything associated with it, in every page?

I want the code to be clean and efficient. That's my motivation in this question.

Comment: Please provide your code of what you have tried. Also, by the sound of it, this seems like a question more fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dom, he doesn't have a file of code he wants to improve, he just wants a better way to put the same menu in every html file without copy/pasting each time the list of links changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question provides little detail, but it sounds like you want something like a php include. If you are running your site on your local, change the .html files to .php and do `<?php include('includes/navigation.php') ?>` where `includes/navigation.php` is a path to JUST your navigation code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is templates. You cannot do it in plain html... You would need to use a server side language like php. You could also do it with a JavaScript templating language like handlebars or similar, but not in plain html.

Comment: You can also use offline templating through some programs. Like Grunt and Jekyll

Comment: Okay great. I was thinking of something along those lines. So an example would be to create an object in php and use it in all of the pages?

Comment: No... You would just make a file for each template. For example, you can have '_nav.php'. Then in your index.php file you would include the nav template '<?php include('_nav.php'); ?>'

Comment: @OdraEncoded Yep, exactly right. I use codekit quite a bit for basic sites, and that has a simple templating feature built in as well. A lot of options out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use PHP or some other server side technology for a simple menu, you can try various Javascript plugins like [MenuCool](http://www.menucool.com/vertical/html-menu-in-separate-file).